# Python 2.7: cann't call subclass's method which inherits from HTMLParser

Tags: python

I define a subclass which inherits from `HTMLParser`

MyHTMLParser.py:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
import urllib

# create a subclass and override the handler methods
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self, url):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)        
        self.url = url
        self.__html = ""
        self.data = urllib.urlopen(url).read() 
        self.feed(self.data)

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        print "Encountered a start tag:", tag

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        print "Encountered an end tag :", tag

    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.__html += data

    def myMethod(self):
        print self.__html



parser = MyHTMLParser("http://gushiwen.org")
parser.myMethod()
```

when i run `python MyHTMLParser.py` (os is windows),it throws the error:

```
    parser.myMethod()
AttributeError: MyHTMLParser instance has no attribute 'myMethod'
```

why?python version is 2.7.

Comment: can you post the complete traceback

Comment: i ran the code, and i was getting output. please check which file you are running.

Comment: I just copy pasted your code. It works.

Comment: If this code is a snippet of your project, then your problem is elsewhere. Ran the code and it's fine on linux.

Comment: crazy! It's the complete code, i just use it to test HTMLParser lib. i still get this error!

Answer (score 2):

Did you... save your edit? It is a common mistake.

Comment: yes , i have save the file, and i can get handle_starttag's output.
`...
Encountered an end tag : script
Encountered an end tag : body
Encountered an end tag : html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "htmlParser.py", line 28, in <module>
    parser.myMethod()
AttributeError: MyHTMLParser instance has no attribute 'myMethod'`

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem, it caused by indent, if i insert spaces instead of Tab, it works, maybe my IDE's bug.